# Jquery Ajax POST not sending all data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use AJAX to POST to a page and display the results but it's not sending all of the parameters.

```
function change_page(button){
    var parent_div = $(button.parentNode);
    var param = parent_div.attr("id");
    var page = this.value;
    var user = $("#user").val();
    var ip = $("#ip").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "gui_info.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: { param : page, "user" : user, "ip" : ip },
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data){
            parent_div.html(data);
            alert(data);
        }
    }); 
}
```

On the php page it's sending to, I'm using `print_r($_POST)` to see which parameters are actually received. Only `user` and `ip` are succesfully being sent since the response is `Array ( [user] => [ip] => )` whereas the param key/value aren't. I've checked the value of the the variables not being sent, they both exist. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is "this"?  Does it have "value"?

Comment: try consoling those "user" and "ip" variables before ajax. probably they are empty

Comment: @blurd it was the "this" which was causing the issue...thanks for spotting that

Answer (score 6):

You are not seeing the variable in the request because its value is undefined.  Undefined values are not included in the jQuery POST.

For example, when sending data like this...

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    a: 1,
    b: undefined,
    c: false,
    d: null
  }
});
```

...these are the parameters passed in the XHR request:

```
a: 1
c: false
d:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data: {
    page: param,
    url: url,
    ip: ip
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is this :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "gui_info.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: { 
      param : page, 
      user : user, 
      ip : ip 
     },
    dataType: "json",   // pass json in there
    success: function(data){
        parent_div.html(data);
        alert(data);
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
page = $(button).val() //If "button" is an element
```

instead of

```
page = this.value
```

change "this" to your element for getting value